# How to add UIButton at rightmost in UITableView cell

Tags: iphone

I want to add UIButton at the rightmost on cell of UITableView. I m not getting how to do it. Please reply.

Thanks In Advance,
Vikas

Comment: It might help to post the code you're trying.

Answer (score 0):

Set the button as [the `accessoryView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW14) of the cell.

Comment: I have used accessoryView in my code but it is not giving output as i and u expect.